# MySQL Return Count for All Dates in Month, Including Those w/ Zero Results

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have a MySQL table that looks like this:

```
+--------+------------+------------------+
|   id   | account_id |     posted_at    |
+--------+------------+------------------+
|   1    |       1    | 2013-10-05 23:09 |
|   2    |       1    | 2013-10-07 14:24 |
|   3    |       1    | 2013-10-07 01:17 |
|   4    |       1    | 2013-10-09 06:58 |
+--------+------------+------------------+
```

For a particular `account_id` (in this case 1), I want to return this (for dates in the current month):

```
+--------+------------+
|  count |    date    |
+--------+------------+
|    0   | 2013-10-01 |
|    0   | 2013-10-02 |
|    0   | 2013-10-03 |
|    0   | 2013-10-04 |
|    1   | 2013-10-05 |
|    0   | 2013-10-06 |
|    2   | 2013-10-07 |
|    0   | 2013-10-08 |
|    1   | 2013-10-09 |
+--------+------------+
```

I have a SQL query that returns the COUNTS for each date within this month.

```
SELECT 
    DATE(posted_at) AS formatted_date, 
    COUNT(id) AS count 
FROM entries 
WHERE account_id = 1 
    AND MONTH(DATE(posted_at)) = MONTH(NOW()) 
GROUP BY formatted_date 
ORDER BY formatted_date ASC
```

It's just returning this:

```
+--------+------------+
|  count |    date    |
+--------+------------+
|    1   | 2013-10-05 |
|    2   | 2013-10-07 |
|    1   | 2013-10-09 |
+--------+------------+
```

Of course, COUNT doesn't return anything for dates that have no data. I want the result to have a zero for dates with no data.

I've read that you should create a join table of all possible dates. Is this the only way?

Comment: is it returning null or just nothing?

Comment: It's only returning data for the dates that have a count greater than 0. I updated the post.

Comment: Well, you can't `SELECT` data that isn't there (I mean, as values in table fields). Unless you run a loop with a counter _(see: stored procedures)_...

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
Declare @INT DATETIME = null
SELECT COUNT( CASE WHEN @INT IS NOT NULL THEN @INT ELSE NULL END)
```

Im not to sure about mysql but in sql server it would be something like this...

```
SELECT 
    DATE(posted_at) AS formatted_date, 
    COUNT( CASE WHEN IS NOT NULL THEN posted_at ELSE NULL END ) AS [count] 
FROM entries 
WHERE account_id = 1 
    AND MONTH(DATE(posted_at)) = MONTH(NOW()) 
GROUP BY formatted_date 
ORDER BY formatted_date ASC
```

Comment: How would you integrate this into the existing query (from the question)?

Comment: Hmm... Returning an error.
`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IS NOT NULL THEN formatted_date ELSE NULL END ) AS [count] FROM entries WHERE ' at line 3`

Comment: Im sorry then pal the code I have given you will definitely work in sql server but I guess mysql is more different then sql server then I thought, Apologies